# Help to understand the circuit function for me to repair - 30W LED ceiling light

Tags: led, light, repair

I have a 30W LED ceiling light that has an adjustable LED temperature and is dimmable. It has a center lower power night light. It is controlled via an IR remote.

I need advice on how to repair the blown out first PCB for the LED ceiling light.

My goal is to find a direct replacement for the first PCB, else maybe find an equivalent LED driver of some kind to salvage the good working LEDs - maybe without the dimming function.

This seems to be the initial 240V downconverter, in which I see multiple transformers and MOSFETs blown. I cannot just replace individual parts, but most likely need to replace the whole assembly.

[image: LED transformer circuit]

I tried to search for the PCB part number but didn't find anything. I am not sure what the usual input voltage for the LED and/or the 2nd PCB would be. It seems that the second PCB has AC un and not DC. Any ideas or explanation of the circuit would help.

The second PCB I suspect is operating at a lower voltage and probably contains the LED driver circuit in DC, but I don't know what the input requirements and output voltage settings.

I have tested all LEDs on the board and they all work. TI used my multimeter and tested them. Most of them light up in groups of 5-6 LED each time I connect the multimeter in parallel to one LED, so I guess there are in a matrix or some kind of connection.
[image: Overall circuit]

Updated #1 info for 1st power PCB.
From the pictures, it seems the input power stage has failed.
Including the caps, diodes and maybe MOSFETs?
The output stage (LNK306CN) which seems to be a buck regulator? seems intact. Input capacitor to the drain of the Power part is 450v 10uF., output 63v 10uF. Again I cannot tell if its DC or AC, but seems to be DC. Anybody can confirm?
[image: Top PCB explain]

Update #2 info for 2nd power PCB.
No visible damage on this PCB.
Based on the visual, MP4001 Constant Current LED backlight driver is being used. It only support AC inputs.
[image: PCB2]

Comment: It's hard to explain the operation of a circuit that we can't see. You'll need to trace out the schematic to understand it. Why can't you replace individual components?

Comment: The first board is the psu. It looks like it has a failed capacitor. This has probably caused failure of other components. What is the voltage rating of the capacitor between C14 and the transformer on the first board? That will give some idea of the output voltage. What is the voltage rating of C14 on the second board?

Comment: Hi Finbarr, Kartman, I edited with Update #1 to include a clearer pictures of the PCB1 that I can find. Do take a look. As you can see there is damage at the cap next to the transformer and at the bottom side, possibly the MOSFET? and some damage to the PCB as well. I also have include the voltage rating of the caps on this PCB. I will include the 2nd PCB soon

Comment: This circuit is complicated enough that pictures of the PCB are probably not good enough. You'll actually need to follow all the connections and redraw it as a schematic. Also you'll probably need an oscilloscope and a multimeter to debug. If your goal is to mainly have a functioning light, just buy a new one.

Comment: You did a wonderful job writing up this question -- All the pictures, labels etc.    Unfortunately, won't change my ultimate advice.   Go buy a new fixture.   Not worth trying to repair.   To avoid having to do similar again soon, select a fixture from a top-tier manufacturer (i.e. Phillips, etc..)

Comment: Doing it out of interest and hobby for the most part - for the sake of knowing if I could fix it; or at least learn something out of it. Indeed, I will end up buying new fixtures

Comment: The first step towards fixing it is still to draw an accurate schematic.

Comment: If you can figure out what voltage is necessary to drive the LED's, then you could replace both circuit boards, meaning the entirety of the electronics, and buy a replacement power supply to drive the LED's. I would get as efficient as I could, to minimize heat production. The label on the light should give you an idea of how much current you'll need, once you determine the full topology of the LED's. Don't give up! To save the environment, it's good to recycle as much as we can.

Comment: I would also underpower the LED's as well, since that improves their efficiency and life. Good luck!